# Terraform environment variable as object of map of objects

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci, terraform-provider-azure

I iterate over the following map of objects:

```
variable "spokes" {
  description = "(Required) Map for target spokes and their respective attributes."
  type = map(object({
    name                   = string
    environment            = string
    law_id                 = string
    vm_subnet_id           = string
    vm_size                = string
    gitlab_runner_token    = string
    secure_subnet_id       = string
    privatelink_vault_zone = string
    custom_tags            = map(string)
  }))
}
```

But due to the sensitivity of the gitlab_runner_token string, I'd like to obtain it via an environment variable.

How could this be accomplished? i.e:

```
export TF_VAR_spokes["spokename1"].gitlab_runner_token="SuPeRsEcReTtOkEn"
```

---

*Edit 1:
the question regards to how to pass a single map attribute as an environment variable, not how to deal with sensitive variables saved in a var file. This code will be executed from Gitlab CI/CD, so saved tokens in a static file inside the repo are definitely a no-go.*

*Edit 2: state files are stored somewhere else and under different authorization and security settings. So, having clear-text sensitive values there isn't really a major concern for me. Having them saved in the repo files is (a concern), hence having the token as a CI/CD (environment) variable.*

*Edit 3:
Passing a populated var file via Gitlab CI/CD would also work, but it is a bit cumbersome for the developer to keep such an extensive file up to date outside of the repository context. So, I'm keeping this option as a last resort. Same thing applies to passing the entire map as an input (environment) variable.*

Comment: Personally I would mot this particular attribut out and manage it separately if you want to to come from a different source.

Comment: You can achieve that with not-using TF. TF is really bad for keeping secrets, as all secrets end up in a state file in a plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set up a separate variable as a map:

```
variable "gitlab_runner_tokens" {
  description = "Sensitive GitLab runner tokens for each spoke."
  type        = map(string)
}
```

Then remove `gitlab_runner_token` from the `spokes` map.

And merge the two maps as follows:

```
locals {
  combined_spokes = {
    for k, v in var.spokes : k => merge(v, { gitlab_runner_token = var.gitlab_runner_tokens[k] })
  }
}
```

Now you can export it as TF_VAR_ environment variables:

```bash
export TF_VAR_gitlab_runner_tokens='{"spokename1": "SuPeRsEcReTtOkEn", "spokename2": "AnOtHeRsEcReTtOkEn"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case , refering sensitive values in a resource is done through following ways although second way : refering through azure keyvault would be secure.

```
variable "spokes_values" {
   description = "(Required) Map for target spokes and their respective attributes."
    type = map(object({
      name                   = string
      environment            = string
      law_id                 = string
      vm_subnet_id           = string
      vm_size                = string
      gitlab_runner_token    = string
      secure_subnet_id       = string
      privatelink_vault_zone = string
      custom_tags            = map(string)
    }))
  default = {
    spoke1 = {
      name                   = "spoke1"
      environment            = "dev"
      law_id                 = "123456"
      vm_subnet_id           = "/subscriptions/subscription-id/resourceGroups/resource-group-name/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-name/subnets/subnet-name"
      vm_size                = "Standard_DS1_v2"
      gitlab_runner_token    = "my-secret-token"
     secure_subnet_id       = "/subscriptions/subscription-id/resourceGroups/resource-group-name/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-name/subnets/subnet-name"
      privatelink_vault_zone = "my-private-zone-name"
      custom_tags            = {}
    },
    spoke2 = {
      name                   = "spoke2"
      environment            = "prod"
      law_id                 = "789012"
      vm_subnet_id           = "/subscriptions/subscription-id/resourceGroups/resource-group-name/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-name/subnets/subnet-name"
      vm_size                = "Standard_DS2_v2"
      gitlab_runner_token    = "my-other-secret-token"
      secure_subnet_id       = "/subscriptions/subscription-id/resourceGroups/resource-group-name/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-name/subnets/subnet-name"
      privatelink_vault_zone = "my-private-zone-name"
      custom_tags            = {}
    }
  }
  
}
```

One way is you can declare variable to be sensitive:

For one value:

```
variable "gitlab_runner_token" {
  description = "GitLab runner token"
  type        = string
  sensitive   = true
  default     = "my-secret-token"
}
```

For single value output :

```
output "gitlabvar" {
  value = var.gitlab_runner_token
  sensitive = true
}
```

For multiple values

```
variable "gitlab_runner_token" {
  description = "GitLab runner token"
  sensitive   = true

  default = {
    spoke1 = {
      name                   = "spoke1"
      gitlab_runner_token    = "my-secret-token"
    
    },
    spoke2 = {
      name                   = "spoke2"
      gitlab_runner_token    = "my-other-secret-token"
    }
}
}
```

Where the variables value is not shown as output anywhere during plan and apply:

This can be checked
For multiple values:

```
output "gitlabvar" {
  value = var.gitlab_runner_token["spoke1"]
//  sensitive = true
}
```

[image]

```
locals {
  spokes = {
    for spoke_name, spoke_values in var.spokes_values : spoke_name => {
      name                   = spoke_values.name
      environment            = spoke_values.environment
      law_id                 = spoke_values.law_id
      vm_subnet_id           = spoke_values.vm_subnet_id
      vm_size                = spoke_values.vm_size
     gitlab_runner_token    = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.gitlab_runner_token.value
     gitlab_runner_token    = var.gitlab_runner_token["${spoke_values.name}"]
      secure_subnet_id       = spoke_values.secure_subnet_id
      privatelink_vault_zone = spoke_values.privatelink_vault_zone
      custom_tags            = spoke_values.custom_tags
    }
  }
}
```

So it has to be marked sensitive:

```
output "gitlabvar" {
  value = var.gitlab_runner_token["spoke1"]
 sensitive = true
}
```

But the secure way is to store the sensitive values in keyvault and access in terraform by referencing the name:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                        = "expkeyvaultfortoken"
  location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
  purge_protection_enabled    = false
  sku_name = "standard"

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
   object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

   
    certificate_permissions = [
      "Create",
      "Delete",
      "DeleteIssuers",
      "Get",
      "GetIssuers",
      "Import",
      "List",
      "ListIssuers",
      "ManageContacts",
      "ManageIssuers",
      "Purge",
      "SetIssuers",
      "Update",
    ]

    key_permissions = [
      "Backup",
      "Create",
      "Decrypt",
      "Delete",
      "Encrypt",
      "Get",
      "Import",
      "List",
      "Purge",
      "Recover",
      "Restore",
      "Sign",
      "UnwrapKey",
      "Update",
      "Verify",
      "WrapKey",
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "Backup",
      "Delete",
      "Get",
      "List",
      "Purge",
      "Recover",
      "Restore",
      "Set",
    ]
    storage_permissions = [
      "Get","Set"
    ]
  }

  
}




resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "this" { 
  name         = "gitlabtoken"
  value        =  "gsdnjgsgjh3.3jgjshgfdj"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "gitlab_runner_token" {
  name         = "gitlabtoken"
  depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault_secret.this]
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}


The value can be assigned or reference in the following way:
Example:
# Assign the values to the spokes variable
locals {
  spokes = {
    for spoke_name, spoke_values in var.spokes_values : spoke_name => {
      name                   = spoke_values.name
      environment            = spoke_values.environment
      law_id                 = spoke_values.law_id
      vm_subnet_id           = spoke_values.vm_subnet_id
      vm_size                = spoke_values.vm_size
      gitlab_runner_token    = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.gitlab_runner_token.value
      secure_subnet_id       = spoke_values.secure_subnet_id
      privatelink_vault_zone = spoke_values.privatelink_vault_zone
      custom_tags            = spoke_values.custom_tags
    }
  }
}
```

Check if the values are displayed:

```
output "gitlabtoken" {
   value = local.spokes["spoke1"].gitlab_runner_token
  sensitive = true
 }
```

[image]

```
output "gitlabtoken" {
  value = local.spokes["spoke1"].gitlab_runner_token
  sensitive = true
}
```

[image]

[image]

Check out [Protect Sensitive Input Variables | Terraform | HashiCorp Developer](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/configuration-language/sensitive-variables)

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly what I'm looking for. The KeyVault path is definitely the way to go, but in your example, the secret would either require to be manually (or externally) populated in the KV or, if terraform is used for that, the token will again end up saved in a variables file.